# how to remove identical rows and duplicated rows from a cell array?

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array as follow:

- 'FEM'     'FEM'
- 'TPB'    'TP53'
- 'ELL'     'TP53'
- 'SIT1'    'GRB2'
- 'TP53'     'ELL'

  I want the output like this:
- 'TPB'      'TP53'
- 'SIT1'     'GRB2'

Could anyone help me to do that?

Comment: Assuming your cell array is called `A`: `B = A([2 4], :);`.

Comment: i have very large cell array.

Comment: I don't see how a 5 row cell array is large.

Comment: I just shared 5 rows but, I have 39240 rows

Comment: Any help  !!!!!!

Comment: Can you be more clear on the format of the cell array? Is it a 2D cell array where each element is a string, or is this a 1D cell array where each element are strings that are space delimited?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this function:

```
function output = return_desired_output()
% This function returns what I want.

output = {'TPB','TP53';'SIT1' 'GRB2'}
```

Hope it helps ...

Comment: This is a joke, right?  Because it if is, you've got a great sense of humour.

Comment: what's this function

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your structure so I assumed it was

```
{'A','B';...
 'C','D';...
 'E','F'};
```

### Remove all duplicate items

*Ex: {'A','A'}*

```
dupe = zeros(size(A,1),1); 
for row = 1:size(A,1)
  dupe(row) = strcmp(A{row,1},A{row,2});
end

A_noDupes = A(~dupe,:);
```

### Remove all repeated rows

*Ex: Any combination of {'A','B'}, {'B','A'}, {'B','B'}, {'A','A'}, will result in all being removed*

*Note:* This will also remove some but not all dupes too, (i.e. if you have {'E','E'} and {'E','A'}, {'E','E'} will be removed)

```
A = A_noDupes;

for row = 1:size(A,1)
   temp = ismember(A,A(row,:))                  
   repeat(row,1) = length(find(temp(:,1) & temp(:,2))) <= 1
end

A_final = A(~repeat,:);
```

Comment: Thank you too much for your help

Comment: However, the first code worked quite well, but the second part show me this error;    In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

   repeat(row) = (find(temp(:,1) & temp(:,2))
   <= 1)

Comment: Friend, the error is in this line repeat(row) = (find(temp(:,1) & temp(:,2)) <= 1) – what do you mean by <= 1

Comment: everything is ok except that line of code;  Could you plz Help me by fix this line???

Comment: Friend are you there ?your code produce an error could you fix the last line  repeat(row) = (find(temp(:,1) & temp(:,2)) <= 1)