# how to remove duplicated pairs of rows from a cell array?

Tags: matlab

yesterday I posted this question but the friend who help me to solve this question didn't reply me, the line which he wrote have an error.
Could any other person help me; I tried myself but didn't find what i want.
 briefly, 
I want to delete duplicated rows say:{'A','B'; 'B', 'A';'C', 'D'; 'C','D'} 
and keep only one single rows like this:{'A','B';'C','D'}

Example:

'TPB' 'TP53'

'ELL' 'TP53'

'SIT1' 'GRB2'

'ROHA' 'BRCA1'

'TP53' 'ELL'

'ROHA' 'BRCA1'

desired output:

'TPB' 'TP53'

'ELL' 'TP53'

'SIT1' 'GRB2'

'ROHA' 'BRCA1'

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6u8fZadKIp2bEVCN1IxVDBBWG8/view

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove identical rows and duplicated rows from a cell array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44075228/how-to-remove-identical-rows-and-duplicated-rows-from-a-cell-array)

Comment: Plz any help i tried but no results !!!!

Comment: @ RTL, I said that I already posted this questions but the guy who put the code didn't reply me because the second part of his code has an error and I need help to fix it if its right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want unique rows of cell array of strings. you can use `unique` on cell entries to get numeric matrix and then use `unique` (again) with argument `'rows'` on the matrix to get the unique rows:

```
% input cell
C = {'TPB' 'TP53';
    'ELL' 'TP53';
    'SIT1' 'GRB2';
    'ROHA' 'BRCA1';
    'TP53' 'ELL';
    'ROHA' 'BRCA1'};
% get unique cell entries as a numeric array
[~, ~, num] = unique(C,'stable');
% sort columns to eliminate [a,b;b,a] situations
num = sort(reshape(num,size(C)),2);
% get unique rows indexes
[~,idx,~] = unique(num,'rows');
res = C(idx,:)
```

outputs:

```
4×2 cell array

'TPB'     'TP53' 
'ELL'     'TP53' 
'SIT1'    'GRB2' 
'ROHA'    'BRCA1'
```

Comment: Thanks friend for your answer but i get this error:                            Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in PPIHumanNet_datas (line 31)
uniqueRows = rows(doubleUnique);

Comment: i' m working with a huge in put cell of size <36888x2 cell>

Comment: i can share it with you if its possible

Comment: upload it to some file sharing system (google drive, dropbox, etc.) and share download link

Comment: I have edited the question and share the data and many thanks for your willng to help me!